# Validate XML using XSD, a Catalog Resolver, and JAXP DOM for XSLT

Tags: java, xml, dom, xslt, xsd

## Background

As [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25698765/59087) describes, there does not appear to be a canonical way to validate XML files against an XSD then subsequently transform them using an XSL template with file paths determined from a catalog resolver.

The XSL templates can be XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0, the latter requiring [Saxon9HE](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/).

## Problem

The [given answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25698765/59087) works, but has a number of issues that are undesirable, including:

- Using an `XMLCatalogResolver` *and* a `CatalogResolver`.
- Creating an **XML catalog resolver** instance using the **catalog resolver** instance.
- Traversing a DOM to determine the XSD URI.
- Creating a `SchemaFactory` to perform the validation.
- Calling the **XML catalog resolver** instance to find the local XSD file path.
- Passing the **catalog resolver** instance to the **XSL transformer** instance.

It seems like those aspects of the code should be handled by existing APIs, especially the contortions required to extract the XSD URI from the DOM.

## Source

A [repository](https://bitbucket.org/djarvis/validating-catalog-resolver/src/master/) exists that contains the entire example, complete with catalog files, schema definitions, and XML tests. The main source file that has the problems noted above follows:

```
package src;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;

import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;

import org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.CatalogResolver;
import org.apache.xerces.util.XMLCatalogResolver;
import static org.apache.xerces.jaxp.JAXPConstants.JAXP_SCHEMA_LANGUAGE;
import static org.apache.xerces.jaxp.JAXPConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA;

import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;

import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource;

import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

/**
 * Download http://xerces.apache.org/xml-commons/components/resolver/CatalogManager.properties
 */
public class TestXSD {
  private final static String ENTITY_RESOLVER =
    "http://apache.org/xml/properties/internal/entity-resolver";

  /**
   * This program reads an XML file, performs validation, reads an XSL
   * file, transforms the input XML, and then writes the transformed document
   * to standard output.
   *
   * args[0] - The XSL file used to transform the XML file
   * args[1] - The XML file to transform using the XSL file
   */
  public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception {
    // For validation error messages.
    ErrorHandler errorHandler = new DocumentErrorHandler(); 

    // Read the CatalogManager.properties file.
    CatalogResolver resolver = new CatalogResolver();
    XMLCatalogResolver xmlResolver = createXMLCatalogResolver( resolver );

    logDebug( "READ XML INPUT SOURCE" );
    // Load an XML document in preparation to transform it.
    InputSource xmlInput = new InputSource( new InputStreamReader(
      new FileInputStream( args[1] ) ) );

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbFactory.setAttribute( JAXP_SCHEMA_LANGUAGE, W3C_XML_SCHEMA );
    dbFactory.setNamespaceAware( true );

    DocumentBuilder builder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    builder.setEntityResolver( xmlResolver );
    builder.setErrorHandler( errorHandler );

    logDebug( "PARSE XML INTO DOCUMENT MODEL" );
    Document xmlDocument = builder.parse( xmlInput );

    logDebug( "CONVERT XML DOCUMENT MODEL INTO DOMSOURCE" );
    DOMSource xml = new DOMSource( xmlDocument );

    logDebug( "GET XML SCHEMA DEFINITION" );
    String schemaURI = getSchemaURI( xmlDocument );

    logDebug( "SCHEMA URI: " + schemaURI );

    if( schemaURI != null ) {
      logDebug( "CREATE SCHEMA FACTORY" );
      // Create a Schema factory to obtain a Schema for XML validation...
      SchemaFactory sFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance( W3C_XML_SCHEMA );
      sFactory.setResourceResolver( xmlResolver );

      logDebug( "CREATE XSD INPUT SOURCE" );
      String xsdFileURI = xmlResolver.resolveURI( schemaURI );

      logDebug( "CREATE INPUT SOURCE XSD FROM: " + xsdFileURI );
      InputSource xsd = new InputSource(
        new FileInputStream( new File( new URI( xsdFileURI ) ) ) );

      logDebug( "CREATE SCHEMA OBJECT FOR XSD" );
      Schema schema = sFactory.newSchema( new SAXSource( xsd ) );

      logDebug( "CREATE VALIDATOR FOR SCHEMA" );
      Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

      logDebug( "VALIDATE XML AGAINST XSD" );
      validator.validate( xml );
    }

    logDebug( "READ XSL INPUT SOURCE" );
    // Load an XSL template for transforming XML documents.
    InputSource xslInput = new InputSource( new InputStreamReader(
      new FileInputStream( args[0] ) ) );

    logDebug( "PARSE XSL INTO DOCUMENT MODEL" );
    Document xslDocument = builder.parse( xslInput );

    transform( xmlDocument, xslDocument, resolver );
    System.out.println();
  }

  private static void transform(
    Document xml, Document xsl, CatalogResolver resolver ) throws Exception
  {
    if( versionAtLeast( xsl, 2 ) ) {
      useXSLT2Transformer();
    }

    logDebug( "CREATE TRANSFORMER FACTORY" );
    // Create the transformer used for the document.
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    tFactory.setURIResolver( resolver );

    logDebug( "CREATE TRANSFORMER FROM XSL" );
    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer( new DOMSource( xsl ) );

    logDebug( "CREATE RESULT OUTPUT STREAM" );
    // This enables writing the results to standard output.
    Result out = new StreamResult( new OutputStreamWriter( System.out ) );

    logDebug( "TRANSFORM THE XML AND WRITE TO STDOUT" );
    // Transform the document using a given stylesheet.
    transformer.transform( new DOMSource( xml ), out );
  }

  /**
   * Answers whether the given XSL document version is greater than or
   * equal to the given required version number.
   *
   * @param xsl The XSL document to check for version compatibility.
   * @param version The version number to compare against.
   *
   * @return true iff the XSL document version is greater than or equal
   * to the version parameter.
   */
  private static boolean versionAtLeast( Document xsl, float version ) {
    Element root = xsl.getDocumentElement();
    float docVersion = Float.parseFloat( root.getAttribute( "version" ) );

    return docVersion >= version;
  }

  /**
   * Enables Saxon9's XSLT2 transformer for XSLT2 files.
   */
  private static void useXSLT2Transformer() {
    System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
      "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
  }

  /**
   * Creates an XMLCatalogResolver based on the file names found in
   * the given CatalogResolver. The resulting XMLCatalogResolver will
   * contain the absolute path to all the files known to the given
   * CatalogResolver.
   *
   * @param resolver The CatalogResolver to examine for catalog file names.
   * @return An XMLCatalogResolver instance with the same number of catalog
   * files as found in the given CatalogResolver.
   */
  private static XMLCatalogResolver createXMLCatalogResolver(
    CatalogResolver resolver ) {
    int index = 0;
    List files = resolver.getCatalog().getCatalogManager().getCatalogFiles();
    String catalogs[] = new String[ files.size() ];
    XMLCatalogResolver xmlResolver = new XMLCatalogResolver();

    for( Object file : files ) {
      catalogs[ index ] = (new File( file.toString() )).getAbsolutePath();
      index++;
    }

    xmlResolver.setCatalogList( catalogs );

    return xmlResolver;
  }

  private static String[] parseNameValue( String nv ) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "\\s*(\\w+)=\"([^\"]*)\"\\s*" );
    Matcher m = p.matcher( nv );
    String result[] = new String[2];

    if( m.find() ) {
      result[0] = m.group(1);
      result[1] = m.group(2);
    }

    return result;
  }

  /**
   * Retrieves the XML schema definition using an XSD.
   *
   * @param node The document (or child node) to traverse seeking processing
   * instruction nodes.
   * @return null if no XSD is present in the XML document.
   * @throws IOException Never thrown (uses StringReader).
   */
  private static String getSchemaURI( Node node ) throws IOException {
    String result = null;

    if( node.getNodeType() == Node.PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE ) {
      ProcessingInstruction pi = (ProcessingInstruction)node;

      logDebug( "NODE IS PROCESSING INSTRUCTION" );

      if( "xml-model".equals( pi.getNodeName() ) ) {
        logDebug( "PI IS XML MODEL" );

        // Hack to get the attributes.
        String data = pi.getData();

        if( data != null ) {
          final String attributes[] = pi.getData().trim().split( "\\s+" );

          String type = parseNameValue( attributes[0] )[1];
          String href = parseNameValue( attributes[1] )[1];

          // TODO: Schema should = http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
          //String schema = attributes.getNamedItem( "schematypens" );

          if( "application/xml".equalsIgnoreCase( type ) && href != null ) {
            result = href;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      // Try to get the schema type information.
      NamedNodeMap attrs = node.getAttributes();

      if( attrs != null ) {
        // TypeInfo.toString() returns values of the form:
        // schemaLocation="uri schemaURI"
        // The following loop extracts the schema URI.
        for( int i = 0; i < attrs.getLength(); i++ ) {
          Attr attribute = (Attr)attrs.item( i );
          TypeInfo typeInfo = attribute.getSchemaTypeInfo();
          String attr[] = parseNameValue( typeInfo.toString() );

          if( "schemaLocation".equalsIgnoreCase( attr[0] ) ) {
            result = attr[1].split( "\\s" )[1];
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      // Look deeper for the schema URI.
      if( result == null ) {
        NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();

        for( int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++ ) {
          result = getSchemaURI( list.item( i ) );

          if( result != null ) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return result;
  }

  /**
   * Writes a message to standard output.
   */
  private static void logDebug( String s ) {
    System.out.println( s );
  }
}
```

The most problematic parts of the code are the:

- `getSchemaURI` method; and
- `if( schemaURI != null ) { ... }` code block.

I think that they are redundant and brittle, but do not know what mechanisms are available to avoid having to manually parse and validate against an XSD whose file path is looked up using an XML catalog.

## Question

Without directly involving SAX, how do you use a catalog resolver to both validate XML files using an XSD *and* transform documents (in DOM) whose XSL file paths are specified in the catalog?

## Related

- http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xcatalogs.html
- http://xerces.apache.org/xml-commons/components/resolver/resolver-article.html
- http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/03/03/catalogs.html
- http://saxonica.com/documentation/sourcedocs/xml-catalogs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  /**
   * Retrieves the XML schema definition using an XSD.
   *
   * @param node The document (or child node) to traverse seeking processing
   * instruction nodes.
   * @return null if no XSD is present in the XML document.
   * @throws IOException Never thrown (uses StringReader).
   */
  private static String getSchemaURI( Node node ) throws IOException {
    String result = null;

    if( node.getNodeType() == Node.PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE ) {
      ProcessingInstruction pi = (ProcessingInstruction)node;

      logDebug( "NODE IS PROCESSING INSTRUCTION" );

      if( "xml-model".equals( pi.getNodeName() ) ) {
        logDebug( "PI IS XML MODEL" );

        // Hack to get the attributes.
        String data = pi.getData();

        if( data != null ) {
          final String attributes[] = pi.getData().trim().split( "\\s+" );

          String type = parseNameValue( attributes[0] )[1];
          String href = parseNameValue( attributes[1] )[1];

          // TODO: Schema should = http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
          //String schema = attributes.getNamedItem( "schematypens" );

          if( "application/xml".equalsIgnoreCase( type ) && href != null ) {
            result = href;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      // Try to get the schema type information.
      NamedNodeMap attrs = node.getAttributes();

      if( attrs != null ) {
        // TypeInfo.toString() returns values of the form:
        // schemaLocation="uri schemaURI"
        // The following loop extracts the schema URI.
        for( int i = 0; i < attrs.getLength(); i++ ) {
          Attr attribute = (Attr)attrs.item( i );
          TypeInfo typeInfo = attribute.getSchemaTypeInfo();
          String attr[] = parseNameValue( typeInfo.toString() );

          if( "schemaLocation".equalsIgnoreCase( attr[0] ) ) {
            result = attr[1].split( "\\s" )[1];
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      // Look deeper for the schema URI.
      if( result == null ) {
        NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();

        for( int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++ ) {
          result = getSchemaURI( list.item( i ) );

          if( result != null ) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return result;
  }
```

First off: The combination of 2-space tabs and new lines for elses on if-else statements is making it hard to read for me.

Now, I don't have a solution for your main problems. I think you'll have to ask somewhere else for that; I can't help you refactor out huge parts of your program just like that. All I can do is review the code as it is based on my knowledge in Java.

I believe this method suffers because you try to validate everything before deciding whether you're going to use it.

```
        // Hack to get the attributes.
        String data = pi.getData();

        if( data != null ) {
          final String attributes[] = pi.getData().trim().split( "\\s+" );
```

`data` has no other uses. So why not do

```
          final String attributes[] = data.trim().split( "\\s+" );
```

instead?

---

```
          final String attributes[] = pi.getData().trim().split( "\\s+" );

          String type = parseNameValue( attributes[0] )[1];
          String href = parseNameValue( attributes[1] )[1];

          // TODO: Schema should = http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
          //String schema = attributes.getNamedItem( "schematypens" );

          if( "application/xml".equalsIgnoreCase( type ) && href != null ) {
            result = href;
          }
```

After this bit of code, you `return result`. There's an else block, but it's not executed if this snippet of code is reached.

In that light, there's no other uses for `type` and `href` in this function. Additionally, `result` was `null` to begin with.

So all that's actually relevant is to do this:

```
          final String attributes[] = pi.getData().trim().split( "\\s+" );

          String type = parseNameValue( attributes[0] )[1];

          // TODO: Schema should = http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
          //String schema = attributes.getNamedItem( "schematypens" );

          if( "application/xml".equalsIgnoreCase( type )) {
            result = parseNameValue( attributes[1] )[1]; //href
          }
```

Validating whether `href` is null is not needed since you're just setting `null` to `null` otherwise anyway.

I also feel this function should be split in three:

One function for `ProcessingInstruction` nodes.

One function for determining `SchemaURI` from `node.getAttributes()`

and one function for determining `SchemaURI` from `node.getChildNodes()`.

This will get rid of the deep nesting of statements you have here and make it easier to understand your code.